# Why do I need to install MSVC++ redist.?

Tags: visual-studio, winapi, visual-c++, msvcrt

I'm in the process of learning VC++ but I wonder why do end-users also need MSVC++?

As far as I can see in MSDN most if not all of the libraries that my programs use (the actual DLL files) already come with the system itself (user32.dll, kernel32.dll, etc).

But how come Paint and Notepad do not need MSVC++, but my software, which is way more simple than Notepad requires this runtime? What does the runtime do? How does it work? Is there a way to make my software work without MSVC++?

Comment: Notepad and Paint actually *do* use the MSVC runtime DLL.  But it is one that Microsoft deploys as part of the Windows install and is specific to Windows programs, c:\windows\system32\msvcrt.dll.  You'll need to deploy your own when you compile with /MD, the version that's specific to the VS version you use.

Comment: Also beware that `msvcrt.dll` is not compatible across Windows versions. While the WDK can be used to link against `msvcrt.dll` (i.e. VS6 runtime), newer targets will use functions that aren't in older versions of `msvcrt.dll`, e.g. on XP. So even though this DLL got promoted to be a "system DLL" starting with XP, it has its caveats.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The runtime provides all the standard functions and classes, like `std::string` and `std::vector`, as well as the support code that runs constructors and destructors of global objects, finds exception handlers, etc.  Windows comes with a version of all this, and for a while Visual C++ used it, but it was discovered that there were incompatibilities with the Standard, so newer versions of the compiler come with fixes (Windows can't bundle the new fixes in place of the old DLLs, because it would break existing programs).

Yes you can avoid the need for the runtime redistributable installer.  You can use the `/MT` build option, which bundles all the required library functions right into your executable.  After that, you'll only need DLLs that come with Windows.

The setting is in Project Configuration under C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library

But note that this will make your executable file somewhat larger, and any bug fixes (especially security fixes distributed via Windows Update) won't affect your program, since you have a particular implementation baked in.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Ben's answer:

The runtime bundles a lot of features for each respective version of Visual Studio. The main advantage of using the DLL version of the runtime is that you get (security) updates "for free" whenever the system updates the DLLs in question.

Another advantage that some people will point out is that it saves resources to use the DLL version *if* many processes use the runtime via the DLL. This is because Windows has a mechanism to share DLLs in memory across processes (or the major part of them).

You will notice that bundling the runtime into your binary - also called **static linking** - will make your binary bigger, because each of your binaries now carries its own version of the runtime (that cannot be replaced without linking the program anew).

Also beware of mixing (your own) DLLs that statically link to either different versions of the runtime (i.e. Debug vs. Release) or that dynamically and statically link to the runtime depending on the DLL. The problem here is allocators. The functions to allocate (`malloc`, `calloc`, `new`) and free memory are incompatible across these. The best method in such a case is to use an independent mechanism such as `IMalloc` - or carry the deallocator inside your object instances always, ensuring that the call to `free`/`delete` doesn't cross module boundaries, even if the instance is handled in another module.